# Get data from multiple select in javascript on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with getting the selected data from my multiselect into my javascript datastring when the submit button is pressed.

So I have this select:

```html
<select multiple class="form-control" name="DivisionSelect[]">
  <option value="|TD">Traffic Division</option>
  <option value="|CP">Metro - C Platoon</option>
  <option value="|DP">Metro - D Platoon</option>
</select>
```

I want the selected data to be lined next to each other like this: "|TD|DP" if Traffic and D Platoon are selected. How can I do this?

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: How are you creating _datastring_?

Comment: var dataString = 'Crime='+ Crime + '&Type='+ Type + '&DescriptionForm='+ DescriptionForm +'&PinID='+ PinID + '&CordX='+ CordX + '&CordY='+ CordY + '&UserID='+ UserID + '&DivSelect='+ UseDiv + '&Divs='+ selecteddivs;

Comment: @St3fanNL i added submit example in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join()` on `select` value and add it to string.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var str = '&Divs="' + $(this).val().join('') + '"';
  console.log(str)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple class="form-control" name="DivisionSelect[]">
  <option value="|TD">Traffic Division</option>
  <option value="|CP">Metro - C Platoon</option>
  <option value="|DP">Metro - D Platoon</option>
</select>
```

To get this value on form submit you can use `submit` event on `form` and get  value of `select` using `find`

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var value = $(this).find('select[name="DivisionSelect[]"]').val();
  var str = '&Divs="' + (value ? value.join('') : '') + '"';
  console.log(str)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <select multiple class="form-control" name="DivisionSelect[]">
  <option value="|TD">Traffic Division</option>
  <option value="|CP">Metro - C Platoon</option>
  <option value="|DP">Metro - D Platoon</option>
</select>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: How can I only make this work on the select with name DivisionSelect?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("select").change(function() {

  var value = $("select option:selected").map(function() {


    return $(this).val()
  }).get().join("")

  console.log("&Divs="+value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple class="form-control" name="DivisionSelect[]">
  <option value="|TD">Traffic Division</option>
  <option value="|CP">Metro - C Platoon</option>
  <option value="|DP">Metro - D Platoon</option>
</select>
```

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

> Description: Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

Comment: And how can I ge this under my "submit" form? Can I make it do this when someone hits the submit button?

Comment: yes just change the `$("select").change(function() {` with you `$("form").submit(function() {

Answer (score 0):

Hev you tried, to read out the selected option, and then appending them to a String? You can append via concat() :

```
var str1 = "Hello ";
var str2 = "world!";
var res = str1.concat(str2);
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I Think below code will work for you.

```
var querystring = "&DivisionSelect=";
$('[name="DivisionSelect"] :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
  querystring += $(selected).val()+querystring; 
});
alert(querystring);
```